# Write duplicate rows found in the list to email body

Tags: c#

The question is how to write values from list to email body if I am getting the whole row as an output? Any suggestions how this should be done?

No errors, but also no output.

```
    // Check if duplicates has been found = list is not empty. Write duplicates to Email message by creating a string with duplictes. 

    if (duplicatesPOSTADR?.Any() != false)
    {
        string combindedString = string.Join("\n", duplicatesPOSTADR);
        string EmailBody = "There was an error and" +
            "following duplicates has been found in POSTADR column: " + combindedString; // collect duplicate values to "combindedString"

        CreateMailItem(EmailBody); // Create email message with body text
        Console.WriteLine(EmailBody); // write to console
    }

}
```

Output in outlook email should look like:

```
There was an error and following duplicates has been found in POSTADR column:

    Fiat, Punto, 500, P4
    BMW, E64, SE0, P4
```

Here is separate method I use for email:

```
    public static void CreateMailItem(string EmailBody)
    {
        //Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)
        // this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        //string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Data\Robot.jpg");
        //string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(path);

        mailItem.Subject = "There was an error";
        mailItem.To = "email@example.com";
        //mailItem.Attachments.Add(files);
        mailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        string msgHTMLBody = "<html><body>" +
            EmailBody + "</body></html>";
        mailItem.HTMLBody = msgHTMLBody;
        mailItem.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
        mailItem.Display(false);
        mailItem.Send();
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
```

Here is full process that can be tested: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEnpmj

Comment: Put a `Select` **before** your `Where` that returns a `string`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text

Comment: @possum just curious, what would you do with screenshot text if it would be a text? The same text can be seen in dotnetfiddle. It can't be copied from there. I haven't seen any reason I need to retype it here.

Comment: What do you want to combine? `NAME` or `POSTADR` or what?

Comment: @hatman Copy and paste for searching for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to show `POSTADR` value which is `duplicate` over multiple rows. You should `Select(x => x.POSTADR)` and apply `Distinct()` on that like below.

```
string combindedString = string.Join("\n", duplicatesPOSTADR.Select(x => x.POSTADR).Distinct());
```